# Antlr4 grammar not-greedy does not stop matching

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have this grammar:

```
grammar Test;

startnode
:
    BEGIN PART_A

    (
    dont_care |
    care
    )*

    END PART_A EOF
;

dont_care
:
    BEGIN I_DONT_CARE

    .*?

    END I_DONT_CARE
;

care
:
    BEGIN CARE

    VALUE STRING

    END CARE
;

BEGIN : '/begin';
END : '/end';
PART_A : 'PART_A';
I_DONT_CARE : 'I_DONT_CARE';
CARE : 'CARE';
VALUE : 'VALUE';
STRING : '"' .*? '"';
WS : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ -> skip;
```

And the following input:

```
/begin PART_A

/begin I_DONT_CARE

    something something

/end I_DONT_CARE

/begin I_CARE

    VALUE "Hello World"

/end I_CARE

/end PART_A
```

The problem is, that the dont_care rule does never stop matching, even though I used the non-greey operator. How can I fix that?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use lexical modes for this.  Please see the book or the answer I just gave to the last question ;)